# Fitting code-chunks to a probability distribution function on two variables

Tags: matlab, distribution, probability

I am sorry for this complicated problem, but, I will try my best to explain myself.

This is basically a **Hidden Markov Model** question. I have two columns of data. The data in these two columns are independent of each other, however, together represent a specific movement which can be character-coded. I assign a character in 3rd column by putting conditions on column1 and column2 entry. Note: the characters are finite (~10-15).

For example:-

```
if (column1(i)>0.5) && (column2(i)<15)
column3(i)='D';
```

I end up with a string something like this

```
AAAAADDDDDCCCCCFFFFAAAACCCCCFFFFFFDDD
```

So, each of the character gets repeated but not of constant lengths (e.g first time A's appear 5 times while second time A's appear 4 times only).

Now, let us take the first chunk of A's (AAAAA), each A containing an ordered pair of column1 and column2 values. Now, comparing with the second chunk of A's (AAAA), the values of column1 and column2 should be similar to those of first chunk. Usually, the values in each columns would be either increasing or decreasing or constant throughout a chunk. And the values of the columns in both chunks should be similar. For example, column1 goes from -1 to -5 in 5 unequal samples but in second chunk it goes from -1.2 to -5.1 in 4 unequal steps.

What I want is a fitting of a probability distribution over column1 and column2 values (independently) for each set of repeated characters (e.g. for A's and then D's then C's then F's and then again A's).

And the final goal is following:-
given n elements in column1, column2, column3, I want to predict what is (n+1) element is going to be in column 3, how many times it is going to repeat itself (with probability e.g. 70% chance it is going to repeat itself 4 times and 20% chance it is going to repeat itself 5 times). Also, what is the probability distribution of column1 and column2 is going to be for the predicted character.

Please feel free to ask questions if I fail to explain it well.

Comment: It looks like this might be a type of hidden Markov model. (Maybe -- it's not clear from the description.) What about the values of column1 and column2 -- I guess there is some dependence from one step to the next? What is that dependence? I think the way to go about this is to try to estimate parameters for column1 and column2 and then infer the runs of letters based on that. But I'm guessing a lot. Maybe you can give more detail.

Comment: @RobertDodier  It is indeed HMM. Thanks for asking. I edited the question above, hopefully, I am clearer and haven't messed up.